# Google Sheets stack arrays with loop

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I am looking for a function that will allow me to stack several arrays of n * 2 in size in a loop style fashion.
My input is a list of sheet names that I need to loop over, read a range from each sheet and output n * 2 array of {sheet_name, value1; sheet_name, value2...}.

I tried organizing my way around it with a LET() function and nesting inside another array formula like MAP or BYROW but the parent won't allow the inner output sizes. I can't seem to wrap my head around solving this so any help is appreciated, no matter how long or short.

**Example of desired input range [A1:A3]:**

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Sheet1 |
| 2 | Sheet2 |
| 3 | Sheet3 |

**Current formula that does the job for me (with hardcoded input sheet names):**

```
=VSTACK({"Data sheet", "Data reference"},
  MAP(TRANSPOSE(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!3:3")),LAMBDA(x,{"Sheet1",x})),
  MAP(TRANSPOSE(INDIRECT("'Sheet2'!3:3")),LAMBDA(x,{"Sheet2",x})),
  MAP(TRANSPOSE(INDIRECT("'Sheet3'!3:3")),LAMBDA(x,{"Sheet3",x}))
)
```

**Example output:**

| Data sheet | Data reference |
| --- | --- |
| Sheet1 | s1_value1 |
| Sheet1 | s1_value2 |
| Sheet2 | s2_value1 |
| Sheet2 | s2_value2 |
| Sheet2 | s2_value3 |
| Sheet3 | s3_value1 |

**Edit:**
[Link to example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fjxMMMC3AAL8b4oROxG8X29v2DvWe2kD_J9UKoK3ihM/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: While one can answer your literal question by making a centralized formula that replaces your hardcoded one, it may still be helpful to you to share an editable *example sheet* in case the hardcoded formula itself can be achieved with simpler/more efficient alternatives or in case the hardcoded formula has issues, whether directly or when compounded with the outer formulas. That can be a consideration for future questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following in `B1` should produce the same result as your current hardcoded formula

```js
=VSTACK({"Data sheet", "Data reference"},
        reduce(col(,1),A1:A3,lambda(a,c,
            vstack(a,
                   MAP(TRANSPOSE(INDIRECT(c&"!3:3")),LAMBDA(x,hstack(c,x))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`REDUCE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568597?hl=en):

```cpp
=REDUCE(TOCOL(,1),A1:A3,LAMBDA(acc,tab,IFNA(VSTACK(acc,HSTACK(tab,INDIRECT(tab&"!A1:A2"))))))
```